# JavaFX HTMLEditor Trigger Font Size Change Programmatically

Tags: java, javafx

I have an HTML editor where I hide the entire toolbar. I want to allow users to change the font size using a context menu instead. I think the safest way to modify the HTML in the editor is to trigger a change event on the toolbar ComboBox that changes the font size. In this example for simplicity I'm trying to trigger that change with a button click.

In the example below I create a standard HTML Editor, then the button that tries to extract the ComboBox from the editor, set its value to the first option, and fire an action event on it. So if you have some text selected in the editor and press the button, the font size of the selected text should change. But it does not.

I've succeeded in this approach with the toolbar toggle buttons and color pickers, but can't get it to work for the ComboBoxs.

EDIT
Here is my reproducible example:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

public class Main extends Application {
    
    boolean ifLoadComplete = false;
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage _primaryStage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPrefWidth(800);
        vBox.setPrefHeight(800);

        HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
        vBox.getChildren().add(editor);
        
        WebView webView = (WebView)editor.lookup("WebView");
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Object>() {

                @SuppressWarnings({"restriction"})
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    // ok mamke sure loading the content ws successful, apparently this gets called a few times?
                    if (newValue != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) { 
                        return; 
                    }       
                    ifLoadComplete = true;
                    
                }
            }
        );

        Button testButton = new Button("Test");
        testButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if (!ifLoadComplete) return;
                
                System.out.println("Setting font size combo!");
                
                ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)editor.lookup(".font-menu-button");
                combo.getSelectionModel().select(3);
                combo.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
            }
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(testButton);
        
        
        String content = "<p>This is a test!</p>";
        webEngine.loadContent(content);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        _primaryStage.setTitle("Test Program");
        _primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        _primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. You can find the css reference guide for HTMLEditor here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#htmleditor

Thanks

Comment: _but all it is is creating a standard editor, then ... then .. then .._ you can't really expect a potential helper to guess your code in the periods, can you? [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

So I also had this problem. You can **only** set it via HTML style tag.

Create a HTML file with style tag for background-color, like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #383838;
                color: #DEDEDE;
                font-family: "sans-serif";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body contentEditable="true">
        YOUR_BODY
    </body>
</html>
```

Use the setHTMLText of the HTMLEditor to add the HTML snippet to your editor

Enjoy a dark background

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. But I'm not trying to set the style of the document body. I'm trying to style text with a background, which involves inserting span tags. And it's tricky because you can't just wrap the current selection in span tags: if there's multiple span tags, they have to be split up so that they're not overlapping. See the HTMLEditor html after adding overlapping background colors to text using the toolbar to see what I mean. I sucessfully accessed and triggered events on the toolbar ToggleButtons and ColorPickers, but you're saying this isnt possible with ComboBox?

Comment: If you have lots of extra information to add, it is better to edit the question than write a long comment.